# segmation fail on 2nd run of the loop

Tags: c, malloc

for some reason I get a segmation fail(core dump) but only on the second run in the loop. some background ptr is declared as char* in main() and initialized as NULL.
Attaching screenshot of the code and prints

```
char* get_command(char **str) {
    char c;
    int i,add=0;
    printf("\tget command\n");

    for(i=0; (c=getchar())!= '\n';i++) {
        if(i==TOTAL_CHAR*add){
            *str = (char*)realloc(*str,sizeof(char)*TOTAL_CHAR*

    (++add));
    printf("\tmemory alocate succede\n");
        if (*str==NULL) {/*warning if realloc has failed*/
            fprintf(stderr,"ERROR:: realloc fail");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    **(str+i)=c;
    printf("\tchar should be: %c, actual: %c\n",c,**(str+i));

    }
    return *str;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f64P2.png)

Comment: Please post all the information as formatted text in the question.

Comment: sorry , I've added it

Comment: Welcome! Please don't *describe* what `main()` does, but post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. The best way to do that is by copy/paste, after you check it compiles and does exhibit the behaviour described. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**(str+i)=c;` it needs to be `*(*str+i)=c;`

```
char* get_command(char **str)
{
    char c;
    int i,add=0;
    printf("\tget command\n");

    for(i=0; (c=getchar())!= '\n';i++)
    {
        *str = (char*)realloc(*str, i + 2);
        if (*str==NULL)
        {/*warning if realloc has failed*/
            fprintf(stderr,"ERROR:: realloc fail\n");
            free(*str);
            exit(0);
        }
    
        *(*str+i)=c;
        printf("\tchar should be: %c, actual: %c\n",c,*(*str+i));
            
    }
    *(*str + i) = 0;   
    return *str;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s = NULL;

    get_command(&s);
    printf("string: \"%s\"\n", s);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/T4PMTjn3s

Comment: it doesn't solve it

Comment: @NivTurk it does